# jquery.each not recognizing dynamically generated DOM structure?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using an AJAX call to get data from PHP server. the return value is a set of HTML tags of `<div>` containing a `<button>`. when the button is clicked, the parent div is replaced with a new one which has a different ID.

the problem is: after a `<div>` gets replaced via the ajax call, jquery seems to only recognize the old set of HTML tags.

all I've found on the internet so far is how to bind events to the dynamically created elements.

please help.

my ajax function is like this:

```
function deal_cards(n, targetSelector, action) {
    var myData = {
        'n': n, // number of cards to get
        'action': action, // type of action
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/test/get_cards',
        data: myData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            if (action == 'append') { // adds cards into selector
                $(targetSelector).append(res.view);
            }

            if (action == 'replace') { // replaces a card
                var newEl = $(res.view);
                console.log('newEl', newEl.attr('id'));
                $(targetSelector).fadeOut('normal', function() {
                    $(targetSelector).replaceWith(newEl);
                    $(targetSelector).fadeIn();
                });
            }

            // shows the IDs of .mycard
            // when called after page load, shows ID 0,1,2,3,4,5
            // after clicking .btn inside div.mycard#3 it still shows ID 0,1,2,3,4,5 instead of 0,1,2,101,4,5
            $('body').find('.mycard').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).attr('id'));
            });
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

this is the php part for the ajax call

```
// php
function get_cards()
{
    $result = array(
        'view' => [],
    );

    $n = $this->input->get('n');
    $action = $this->input->get('action');

    $x = 0;
    $view = '';
    if ($action == 'append')
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
        {
            $x = $i;

            $view .= '<div class="col-md-12 mycard" id="'.$x.'" style="background-color:blue"><button class="btn">click</button></div>';
        }
    }
    else if ($action == 'replace')
    {
        $x = $n+100;

        $view .= '<div class="col-md-12 mycard" id="'.$x.'" style="background-color:blue"><button class="btn">click</button></div>';
    }

    $result['view'] = $view;
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

and this is the html

```
// html
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
    // deals the cards right after page load
    // shows ID 0,1,2,3,4,5
    deal_cards(6, '#container', 'append');

    $('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
        console.log('clicked card #'+$(this).closest('.mycard').attr('id')); // clicked card #3

        deal_cards(1, '#'+$(this).closest('.mycard').attr('id'), 'replace'); // replace the parent div.mycard of the button with a new one
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: sorry for the misspellings, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fadeout is an async operation.

You need to find .mycard in the callback of fadeout.

```
$(targetSelector).fadeOut('normal', function() {
   $(targetSelector).replaceWith(newEl);
   $(targetSelector).fadeIn();
   findCards();
});

function findCards(){
   $('body').find('.mycard').each(function() {
       console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
}
```

Comment: WHAT. THE. HECK!!! DID I JUST WASTE ALL THOSE HAIR AND TIME FOR SOMETHING THIS SIMPLE?!?!?! Thank you so much for this. I never knew it was an async operation.. hope this answer benefits many people.